# Alternating series convergence or divergence $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n n^2}{(n+1)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n n^2}{(n+1)^2}$$

The ratio test came up inconclusive, and I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 3):

Sequence limit not equal to zero, so divergence theorem.

Comment: Okay thanks!  So the limit would equal 1 using L'Hopitals?

Comment: Limit doesn't exist, but the limit of absolute value is $1$. Not necessary to take L'h, dividing $n^2$ both numerator and denominator is enough.